# Register Chrome Extension as GitHub Application?

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, github-api

I want to access GitHub-Information (esp. Bugtracking) in my Chrome Extension. Just like everywhere else I have to create an OAuth token to access the API there. Now my problem is: I have to provide a callback-url. Of course that does not exist in a chrome extension, because it runs on localhost.

Does a workaround exist for that issue?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity)?

Comment: I am not using OAuth to get Chrome/Google credentials, but to access GitHub

Comment: Let me repeat myself. Have you _read_ the documentation? Specifically, `launchWebAuthFlow`

Comment: Obviously: Yes: Read it. But not good enough :). Looks like this is exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into this and it seems that GitHub [does not support](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) method, meaning you'd need to include your client secret in your extension's source, which is an obvious security issue.

Due to this, you should instead get your users to generate and supply their own token via [Personal Access Tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens).